# ERROR 1064 (42000): no such local index in manticore

Tags: go, sphinx, manticore-search

I'm trying to connect to `manticore` database using the official [go-sdk](https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch). I use the docs instructions expect I've added a `DROP` and a `CREATE` statement in order to create `testrt` index programmatically.

```
func FillManticore(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    sess := session.Instance(r)
    cl := manticore.NewClient()
    cl.SetServer("localhost", 9312)
    cl.Open()

    q := "DROP TABLE testrt"
    res, err := cl.Sphinxql(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("create error:", q)
    }

    q = "CREATE TABLE testrt(id int, title text, content text, counter int)"
    fmt.Println("create query is:", q)
    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("create error:", q)
    }

    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(`replace into testrt values(1,'my subject', 'my content', 15)`)
    fmt.Println(res, err)
    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(`replace into testrt values(2,'another subject', 'more content', 15)`)
    fmt.Println(res, err)
    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(`replace into testrt values(5,'again subject', 'one more content', 10)`)
    fmt.Println(res, err)
    res2, err2 := cl.Query("subject", "testrt")
    fmt.Println(res2, err2)
```

But I get:

```
[ERROR 1064 (42000): no such local index 'testrt'] <nil>
[ERROR 1064 (42000): no such local index 'testrt'] <nil>
[ERROR 1064 (42000): no such local index 'testrt'] <nil>
<nil> <nil>
```

The docs is really spare so I could not figure out what is wrong there with my code. So I appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong thing is that you can't add column named `id` as there's one by default. If you try the same query directly with mysql client you'll get:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE testrt(id int, title text, content text, counter int);
ERROR 1064 (42000): error adding index 'testrt': can not add multiple attributes with same name 'id'
```

Here's the fixed code:

```
    cl := manticore.NewClient()
    cl.SetServer("localhost", 9312)
    cl.Open()

    q := "DROP TABLE testrt"
    res, err := cl.Sphinxql(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("create error:", err)
    }

    q = "CREATE TABLE testrt(/*id int, */title text, content text, counter int)"
    fmt.Println("create query is:", q)
    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(q)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("create error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)

    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(`replace into testrt values(1,'my subject', 'my content', 15)`)
    fmt.Println(res, err)
    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(`replace into testrt values(2,'another subject', 'more content', 15)`)
    fmt.Println(res, err)
    res, err = cl.Sphinxql(`replace into testrt values(5,'again subject', 'one more content', 10)`)
    fmt.Println(res, err)
    res2, err2 := cl.Query("subject", "testrt")
    fmt.Println(res2, err2)
```

which returns:

```
[Query OK, 0 rows affected]
[Query OK, 1 rows affected] <nil>
[Query OK, 1 rows affected] <nil>
[Query OK, 1 rows affected] <nil>
Status: ok
Query time: 0s
Total: 3
Total found: 3
Schema:
    Fields:
        title
        content
    Attributes:
        counter: int
        title: string
        content: string
Matches:
    Doc: 1, Weight: 1, attrs: [15 my subject my content]
    Doc: 2, Weight: 1, attrs: [15 another subject more content]
    Doc: 5, Weight: 1, attrs: [10 again subject one more content]
Word stats:
    'subject' (Docs:3, Hits:3)
 <nil>
```

The diff is:

```
8c8
<         fmt.Println("create error:", q)
---
>         fmt.Println("create error:", err)
11c11
<     q = "CREATE TABLE testrt(id int, title text, content text, counter int)"
---
>     q = "CREATE TABLE testrt(/*id int, */title text, content text, counter int)"
15c15
<         fmt.Println("create error:", q)
---
>         fmt.Println("create error:", err)
16a17
>     fmt.Println(res)
26d26
<
```

Comment: Well, now I still get `CREATE TABLE requires data_dir to be set in the config file` . I added  `data_dir = /var/lib/manticore/data` to `searchd {...}`  inside ` /etc/manticoresearch/manticore.conf` but did not resolve the problem. Also noticed `[13552] FATAL: 'data_dir' cannot be mixed with index declarations in '/etc/manticoresearch/manticore.conf'` so not sure where to put `data_dir`

Comment: Read about RT mode vs Plain mode - https://manual.manticoresearch.com/Read_this_first#Real-time-mode-vs-plain-mode

Comment: I did read that useless docs. It was not helpful.

Comment: So you probably read there "You cannot combine the 2 modes and need to decide which one you want to follow". Please remove all `index` declarations from your config, it should help with `'data_dir' cannot be mixed with index declarations`